# how to create a database driven website without placing html files on ftp file manager?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ftp

i;m trying to create a php mysql database driven website. i have one page template and some datas on my website. my temp.php is file written in php mysql and html. it requires a value called "id" to generate a page. all are my other pages depends on the same temp file. for examble if i want to create a page with url like **http://www.examble.com/men **

i place a index.php file on my

**htdocs/men** folder. my index.php file is very simple.

```
 <?php
 id = "men";
 $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
  include "$root/temp.php";
 ?>
```

my temp.php creates a web page for men according to their id place on index.php.

if i wanna create a webpage with ** http://www.examble.com/women ** . i repeating the same procedure with id value = women and place the file in my ftp directory ** htdocs/women** . if any way to avoid uploading same file with different value in ftp directory and achieve same output without using this uploading file? it is posssible to achieve like this? how can i achieve this? i don't want an url like **examble.com/page?u=something** i need a clean url. if any way to achieve this? tnx in advance frnds... my temp.php file is

```
<?php 
value = id;
//codings
?>
```

thats all....sorry for my bad english. tnx in advances...

Answer (score 0):

I would use mod_rewrite for this ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html )

If you use Apache this could be your solution.